# Why does Perl's readdir() cache directory entries?

Tags: perl, file

For some reason Perl keeps caching the directory entries I'm trying to read using [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html):

```
opendir(SNIPPETS, $dir_snippets); # or die...
while ( my $snippet = readdir(SNIPPETS) )
 { print ">>>".$snippet."\n"; }
closedir(SNIPPETS);
```

Since my directory contains two files, *test.pl* and *test.man*, I'm expecting the following output:

```
.
..
test.pl
test.man
```

Unfortunately Perl returns a lot of files that have since vanished, for example because I tried to rename them. After I move *test.pl* to *test.yeah* Perl will return the following list:

```
.
..
test.pl
test.yeah
test.man
```

What's the reason for this strange behaviour? The documentation for [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) and [closedir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html) doesn't mention some sort of caching mechanism. "ls -l" clearly lists only two files.

Comment: Both `readline` and `readdir` pre-read and cache.  It’s the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of `opendir` seems to be a list of files which were in the directory at the time it was called. If you alter the directory you need to call `rewinddir`:

```
my $dir_snippets = "/tmp/fruit";
system ("rm -rf $dir_snippets");
mkdir $dir_snippets or die $!;
my $banana = "$dir_snippets/banana";
system ("touch $banana");
opendir(SNIPPETS, $dir_snippets); # or die...
while ( my $snippet = readdir(SNIPPETS) ) {
    if (-f $banana) {
        unlink $banana;
        rewinddir SNIPPETS;
    }
    print ">>>".$snippet."\n";
}
closedir(SNIPPETS);
```

Gives you

```
>>>.
>>>.
>>>..
```

Without the rewinddir you get

```
>>>.
>>>..
>>>banana
```

Just testing with C, I get the same thing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{
    DIR * fruit;
    struct dirent * file;

    fruit = opendir ("/tmp/fruit");
    if (! fruit) {
        fprintf (stderr, "opendir failed: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (file = readdir (fruit)) {
        unlink ("/tmp/fruit/banana");
        printf (">>> %s\n", file->d_name);
    }
    closedir (fruit);
}
```

Gives the following (after creating the file "banana" with "touch"):

```
$ ./a.out 
>>> .
>>> ..
>>> banana
$ ./a.out 
>>> .
>>> ..
```

Comment: Whoa, works like charm now, thanks! I called opendir() right on top of the script expecting readdir() to do the actual, well, reading.

tl;dr: Either call opendir right before readdir or use rewinddir if you expect changes in the directory you're reading from.